# msdeploy ignore like .hgignore

Tags: .net, asp.net, deployment, msdeploy

is there any way that we can tell **visual Studio 2010 MSDeploy** to ignore some of the files and folders withing the project? currently, the way I do is to exclude things from the project so that they won't be deployed.

as mercurial does, a file like `.hgignore` would be great here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the command line parameter -skip.

For directories:

```
-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=REGEX
```

For files:

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=REGEX
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm, this is interesting. I am guessing you are using a batch file to manage your deployment. I am using VS 2010 publish tool. do u have any batch file code sample to handle the deployment process?